# Equivalent to "Stylish" plug-in for IE 9

Tags: plugins, internet-explorer-9

The [stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome) addon for Firefox allows you to:

> easily install themes and skins for Google, Facebook, YouTube, Orkut, and many, many other sites. You can even customize Firefox and other programs themselves.

Can anyone advise of a similar plug-in that works with IE9?

Specifically I am wanting to customise the style of a particular website that I visit frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a similar extension, but in Tools -> Internet Options -> Accessibility you can specify a user stylesheet to use.

This is much more limited than something like Stylish, since this stylesheet would be global to all sites you'd use in IE, but could be helpful for your particular site, especially if they have a scoped body class or something to limit your changes to that one site.

Just save the styles you want to a .css file and point to it from the Accessibility properties dialog.

Like Stylish, you may need to remember to use `!important` to override existing site styles.

Answer (score 0):

[TrixIE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/trixiewpf45/) is the closest; it works with (most) of the styles supported by Stylish (e.g. those on [UserStyles.org](https://userstyles.org/)).